# Setting multiple boolean variables to false in Java

Tags: java

I need to assign multiple boolean variables to false in java (As a part of my Android Application)

What is the best way to do that?

Is the following method correct? Does it have any drawbacks/pitfalls?

```
boolean showDownloadButton, showOpenFileButton, showProgressBar, showErrorMessage, showDownloadWhenReady;

showDownloadButton = showProgressBar = showOpenFileButton =  showErrorMessage = showDownloadWhenReady = false;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: As another comment, if these booleans are class members, they are automatically initialized to false.   If they are *not* class members, then your design is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no drawback or advantage to this, because each individual variable is set separately anyway. Setting it to `boolean` literal `false` or to a result of another assignment returning `false` makes no difference, apart from the readability.

Note that you could potentially simplify your code by making an array of `boolean`s instead, and using constant indexes to access individual values:

```
static final int DOWNLOAD_BTN = 0;
static final int OPEN_FILE_BTN = 1;
static final int PROGRESS = 2;
static final int ERROR_MSG = 3;
static final int DOWNLOAD_WHEN_RDY = 4;
static final int ELEMENT_COUNT = 5;
...
boolean[] visibility = new boolean[ELEMENT_COUNT];
...
if (visibility[ERROR_MSG]) {
    ...
}
```